# VBA - Range.Row.Count

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple code to illustrate my predicament.

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long

    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
End Sub
```

What happens is this: We count the rows which contain values starting at A1. If the number of rows which contain values is > 1 the code works great. However, if A1 is the only cell which contains any value, k = 1,048,576 which I guess is the maximum number of rows allowed in Excel.

Why doesn't k = 1?

Pictures:

[image: The code works]

[image: This is wrong]

EDIT: The workaround that I'm using is the following:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long

    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    If k = 1048576 Then
        k = 1
    End If
    MsgBox (k)
End Sub
```

Since k is always equal to 1048576 when the number of rows with values is 1. It just feels a bit silly having to do something like this.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Probably a better solution is work upwards from the bottom:

```
k=sh.Range("A1048576").end(xlUp).row
```

Comment: If I use this, it will looped around 5000 times. Will this slow down the code significantly? because counting from 1 million, 5000 times seems a bit inefficient.

Comment: Excel stores information sparsely, so it does not need to look at the intermediate cells. So no, it won't slow down - its very fast

Comment: After testing all the solutions this was the quickest one. Thanks!

Comment: Sheets can have a different number of possible rows depending on the version of Excel. You should use `Rows.Count` instead of that large static number in your range object.

Comment: Why it return Watch 1048569 when I delete some row in table?

Answer (score 10):

You should use `UsedRange` instead like so:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long

    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1
End Sub
```

The `+ rn.Row - 1` part is because the UsedRange only starts at the first row and column used, so if you have something in row 3 to 10, but rows 1 and 2 is empty, `rn.Rows.Count` would be 8

Comment: I can't use this solution because I'm counting the rows in multiple columns. Example: http://i.imgur.com/cdCx0Or.png

Answer (score 5):

```
CountRows = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the "Last" function from Ron de Bruin (http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm), it worked perfectly for me and also gives back the last column and cell if you want. To get the last row use it like

```
lastRow = Last(1,yourRange)
```

I found this quite handy.

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
    Dim lrw As Long
    Dim lcol As Long

    Select Case choice

    Case 1:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 2:
        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

    Case 3:
        On Error Resume Next
        lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                       After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                       Lookat:=xlPart, _
                       LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                       SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                       MatchCase:=False).Row
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
        If Err.Number > 0 Then
            Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
            Err.Clear
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

    End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone looks at this again, you can use this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim k As Long
    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown).End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

That is nice question :)

When you have situation with 1 cell (A1), it is important to identify if second declared cell is not empty (`sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)`). If it is true it means your range got out of control :) Look at code below:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Arkusz1")

Dim k As Long

If IsEmpty(sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)) = True Then
    k = 1

Else
    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

or

```
k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
```

or

```
k = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :-

```
Sub test()

    k = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox (k)

End Sub
```

The /only/ catch is that if there is no data it still returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me especially in pivots table filtering when I want the count of cells with data on a filtered column. Reduce `k` accordingly `(k - 1)` if you have a header row for filtering:

```
k = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A:$A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

since it counts the number of cells until it finds the last one written.

Unlike

```
Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

what it does is **select an "from-to" range and display the row number of the last one busy**.
A range implies two minimum values, so ... meanwhile A1 has a value of the range continues to count to the limit (1048576) then it is shown.

```
Sub test()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Dim k As Long

    k = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox k

    k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    MsgBox k

End Sub
```

[image]