# How to get the sum of the whole column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that gives me the sum of the values from rows A - J but it only adds the values from row 1 - 2. I'm trying to get it to sum the values from row 1 - 10.

```
Sub addcol()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row

Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Column

For j = 1 To lastRow
    For i = 1 To LastColumn
    Cells(lastRow + 1, i) = Cells(lastRow + 1, i) + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(j, i))
    Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop at all?  You can use `SUM` on more than one column at the same time, i.e. `=SUM(A1:E10)`.  Also, if you're simply adding all the values in the range in VBA, just looping through and simply adding them is likely going to be much more performant that repeatedly calling `WorksheetFunction.Sum`.

Comment: @pervis - Agree with Comintern; you are kind of over-complicating this by using VBA.  That said, your code for LastRow and LastColumn are a little excessive. Something like Range.End (see this question for similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056372/vba-range-row-count)